# How to delete a blob in directory created in blob of azure storage account through java?

Tags: java, azure, logic, blob

I want to upload folder on local to blob of azure storage account. 
Code is :

```
   CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("Directory1/Directory2/Directory3/Directory4Directory5/temp.txt");
        File source = new File(filePath);
        blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
        CloudBlobDirectory directoryOfTempFile = container.getDirectoryReference("Directory1/Directory2/Directory3/Directory4Directory5");
        CloudBlockBlob blobToDelete = directoryOfTempFile.getBlockBlobReference("temp.txt");
        blobToDelete.deleteIfExists();
```

How I can delete file Temp.txt?

Comment: What you need to do is list all files in that directory and then upload each file.

Comment: I have no files, I just want to upload a directory structure. What's your suggestion?

Comment: Azure Blob Storage has only 2 level hierarchy - Containers & Blobs. There's no directory as such. You create an illusion of directory by prefixing the blob name with something. For example, let's say you have a blob named `myfile.png` and you want to make it appear in a folder named `images`. The way you would do it is name your blob as `images/myfile.png`. If you want empty directories to persist, please use Azure File Service instead of Blobs.

Comment: I have created files related services but problem is we can't use indexing in that case. So switched to blob.

Comment: Aah....But you can't have an empty directory structure in blob storage. What you could do is upload a zero byte blob in each directory and then that directory structure would persist.

Comment: Thanks, worked on this. I created temp file under directories. Is there any way to delete that temp file after successful creation of directories? My current code deletes whole blob, means complete directory structure..   Please see the question again..

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri  , can you please refer the question and help me out to delete temporary file there under directories?

Comment: Here's the catch. If you delete this temp file, the directory will also be deleted :)

Comment: Ok,Thanks. I thought only file can be deleted.

Comment: Actually the blob you're storing is not `temp.txt`. It is `Directory1/Directory2/Directory3/Directory4Directory5/temp.txt`.

Comment: Right.It's getting stored as single blob and not as file and directories in case of file storage.